# Having a trouble in calling the method

Tags: c#, method-call

I was trying to post my output using **Console.WriteLine(Compute(i))** but it said that "the name i does not exist in the current context".

```
using System;
public class Program
{

public static int Compute(int i)
{
    i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int n = 0; n <= i; n++)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
    return i;
}

public static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");

    Compute(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

    Console.WriteLine(Compute(i));
}
}
```

Thank you guys for those who will help me.

Comment: i is undefined variable in current scope

Comment: you can not use i outside of the Compute Method, use "var i = Compute(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));"

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
public class Program
{

public static int Compute(int i)
{
    i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int n = 0; n <= i; n++)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
    return i;
}

public static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");
    int i=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());// Define i
    Compute(i);

    Console.WriteLine(Compute(i));
}
}
```

Comment: or you can directly   give in your code   @kuroi    Console.WriteLine( Compute(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())));

Comment: Thank you sir sir Cool JK for helping. It was working.

Comment: Kurai here no one is sir.. All are equals because they all have knowledge of different different things and they share them knowledge according to your questions.